# NXLog and long messages

Tags: nxlog

Forwarding windows events using NXLog to JSON format. The problem is that now and then, the JSON message becomes too large/long for the receiving system.

Is there a way to limit/truncate the JSON outputted from NXLog without breaking the JSON?

I have tried to work only on the $Message part, here trying to truncate it at 20 characters... but that doesn't work (infinite loop).

> Exec $Message =~ s/^(.{1,20}).*$/$1/g;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually caused by `$Message` (or `$raw_event`) being too large like you said.
Instead of a regexp I suggest using the [substr()](https://nxlog.co/documentation/nxlog-user-guide#core_func_substr) function to truncate the data:

```
Exec $Message = substr($Message, 0, 20);
```

Comment: Thanks. So can I use the length of raw_event to know how much (little) to remove from message to loose least possible of a total JSON maximum length?